# how can i use more than one array in foreach()?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

i want to send more than on array in foreach() .
i know this way is false .whats the true method ?

```
$Fname = [1,2,3,4,5];
$Lname = [1,2,3,4,5];
$Addrs = [1,2,3,4,5];
$Mobile = [1,2,3,4,5];

$fields = array(
    'name'  => 'a',
    'type'  => 'b',
    'value' => 'n',
    'show'  => 'd',
);



foreach($fields as $key => $n) 
{
    echo " {$Fname[$key]} , {$Lname[$key]},{$Addrs[$key]} , {$Mobile[$key]},{$key} ,{$n} <br>";
}
```

Comment: `$Fname,$Lname,$Addrs,$Mobile`. these arrays are numerical and have same number of values?

Comment: What do you mean by: "This way is false" ?

Comment: its just a examlple !

Comment: becuese this dosnt work

Comment: Wait, so you have an array of first names, last names, addresses, and phone numbers in this example. Why aren't you just storing each as an object or associative arrary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all your arrays have the same number of rows, you can use a `for` loop instead of a `foreach`, in conjunction with `next()` and `current()` for associative array:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($Fname); $i++ )
{
    echo $Fname[$i]  . PHP_EOL;
    echo $Lname[$i]  . PHP_EOL;
    echo $Addrs[$i]  . PHP_EOL;
    echo $Mobile[$i] . PHP_EOL;
    echo current($fields) . PHP_EOL;
    next($fields);
}
```

The problem is that your arrays haven't same rows number...
So you have to add some condition like this:

```
for( $i = 0; $i < count($Fname); $i++ )
{
    echo $Fname[$i]  . PHP_EOL;
    echo $Lname[$i]  . PHP_EOL;
    echo $Addrs[$i]  . PHP_EOL;
    echo $Mobile[$i] . PHP_EOL;
    if( isset(current($fields)) )
    {
        echo current($fields) . PHP_EOL;
        next($fields);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`i know this way is false`...? What's false about it?

`foreach()` will iterate over **an** array, not over multiple arrays.... if you absolutely need to iterate over multiple arrays within the same `foreach()` loop, you can use SPL's [MultipleIterator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php), but it adds a lot more complexity to your code, and the approach that you've taken is as good as any

Just make sure that your keys match up in all the arrays; if they don't then you will have problems

```
foreach(array_values($fields) as $key => $n) 
{
    $k = array_keys($fields)[$key];
    echo " {$Fname[$key]} , {$Lname[$key]},{$Addrs[$key]} , {$Mobile[$key]},{$k} ,{$n} <br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of storing your data like that, it'd be easier to store it in an array of associative arrays:

```
$people = array(
    array(
        'firstName' => 'Bruce',
        'lastName' => 'Wayne',
        'address' => '123 East St. Gotham City, XX USA'
        'mobile' => '847-847-8475'
    ),
    array(
        'firstName' => 'Roland',
        'lastName' => 'Deschain',
        'address' => 'N/A'
        'mobile' => '191-919-1919'
    )
);

foreach($people as $person){
    echo $person['firstName'] + ', ' + $person['lastName'];
    echo $person['address'] + ', ' + $person['mobile'];
}
```

It's just a cleaner way to store/access your data, makes it easy to use one foreach as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

$arr1 = array("a" => 1, "b" => 2, "c" => 3);
 $arr2 = array("x" => 4, "y" => 5, "z" => 6);

foreach ($arr1 as $key => &$val) {}
foreach ($arr2 as $key => $val) {}

var_dump($arr1);
 var_dump($arr2);